# Ошибка pg_result(): Unable to jump to row 1 on PostgreSQL

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Пытаюсь вывести таблицу, состоящую из 3-х строк, в PHP. Первая строка выводится, а вот остальные почему-то не распознаются.

`pg_num_rows($result);` возвращает значение 1. Если же я пытаюсь явно ввести в цикле 3, то опять же первая строка выводится, а дальше ошибки:

```
Warning: pg_result(): Unable to jump to row 1 on PostgreSQL result index 2601263304800 in C:\Server\data\htdocs\hello.php on line 11
Warning: pg_result(): Unable to jump to row 2 on PostgreSQL result index 2601263304800 in C:\Server\data\htdocs\hello.php on line 11
```

Сам вывод таблицы в PHP:

```
$result=pg_query("SELECT * FROM sklad;");
$rows=pg_num_rows($result);
for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
{
    $no=pg_result($result,$i,'no');
    $name=pg_result($result,$i,'name');
    $cena=pg_result($result,$i,'price');
    $ost=pg_result($result,$i,'last');

    print "
    Номер: $no
    Название: $name
    Цена: $cena
    Остаток: $ost
    ";
}
```

Пробовал через `while ($db=pg_fetch_array($result))` - все то же самое.

Подскажите, в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Пробовал через while ($db=pg_fetch_array($result)) - все то же самое

Comment: А там всего одна и есть, судя по вашим же данным.

Comment: Когда я ввожу select * from sklad; в консоли psql, то мне выводятся все 3 строки, так что вряд ли

Comment: Либо вы делаете запросы к разным БД, либо с разными правами доступа. `pg_num_rows` вернул 1 -- значит одна.

Comment: Спасибо, в консоли был подключен к другой бд)) Переподключился к нужной с помощью команды \c dbname

Comment: А Вы случайно не знаете как поменять бд по умолчанию в консоли PostgreSQL ? А то каждый раз приходится подключаться к нужной

Comment: [Маны-маны-маны-маны.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/app-psql.html) Как минимум два способа: задать переменную среды у себя в шелле или сделать файл `~/.psqlrc`, который выполняется при каждом старте psql. Я б предпочёл первое, ибо оверрайдится при необходимости.

Comment: Используй DBeaver с SSH туннэлями. Ну или другой ГУИ. А то писать всё это в консоле каждый раз как-то нелепо.